# Minecraft 1.7.10 crashes when I attempt to open a world

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues

I want to play minecraft in 1.7.10 but after launching it through the launcher and i try to open a server or single player world it crashes

```
---- Minecraft Crash Report ----
// This is a token for 1 free hug. Redeem at your nearest Mojangsta: [~~HUG~~]

Time: 3/18/15 6:11 PM
Description: Ticking screen

java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException
    at java.nio.Buffer.checkIndex(Buffer.java:540)
    at java.nio.DirectIntBufferU.get(DirectIntBufferU.java:253)
    at bma.a(SourceFile:271)
    at bma.a(SourceFile:220)
    at bao.a(SourceFile:1694)
    at bao.a(SourceFile:1652)
    at bjb.a(SourceFile:125)
    at hd.a(SourceFile:70)
    at hd.a(SourceFile:13)
    at ej.a(SourceFile:174)
    at bcx.e(SourceFile:78)
    at bao.p(SourceFile:1343)
    at bao.ak(SourceFile:774)
    at bao.f(SourceFile:728)
    at net.minecraft.client.main.Main.main(SourceFile:148)


A detailed walkthrough of the error, its code path and all known details is as follows:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

-- Head --
Stacktrace:
    at java.nio.Buffer.checkIndex(Buffer.java:540)
    at java.nio.DirectIntBufferU.get(DirectIntBufferU.java:253)
    at bma.a(SourceFile:271)
    at bma.a(SourceFile:220)
    at bao.a(SourceFile:1694)
    at bao.a(SourceFile:1652)
    at bjb.a(SourceFile:125)
    at hd.a(SourceFile:70)
    at hd.a(SourceFile:13)
    at ej.a(SourceFile:174)
    at bcx.e(SourceFile:78)

-- Affected screen --
Details:
    Screen name: bcx

-- Affected level --
Details:
    Level name: MpServer
    All players: 0 total; []
    Chunk stats: MultiplayerChunkCache: 0, 0
    Level seed: 0
    Level generator: ID 00 - default, ver 1. Features enabled: false
    Level generator options: 
    Level spawn location: World: (8,64,8), Chunk: (at 8,4,8 in 0,0; contains blocks 0,0,0 to 15,255,15), Region: (0,0; contains chunks 0,0 to 31,31, blocks 0,0,0 to 511,255,511)
    Level time: 0 game time, 0 day time
    Level dimension: 0
    Level storage version: 0x00000 - Unknown?
    Level weather: Rain time: 0 (now: false), thunder time: 0 (now: false)
    Level game mode: Game mode: survival (ID 0). Hardcore: false. Cheats: false
    Forced entities: 0 total; []
    Retry entities: 0 total; []
    Server brand: ~~ERROR~~ NullPointerException: null
    Server type: Non-integrated multiplayer server
Stacktrace:
    at bjf.a(SourceFile:289)
    at bao.b(SourceFile:1972)
    at bao.f(SourceFile:737)
    at net.minecraft.client.main.Main.main(SourceFile:148)

-- System Details --
Details:
    Minecraft Version: 1.7.10
    Operating System: Windows 7 (amd64) version 6.1
    Java Version: 1.8.0_25, Oracle Corporation
    Java VM Version: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (mixed mode), Oracle Corporation
    Memory: 71006800 bytes (67 MB) / 189317120 bytes (180 MB) up to 1060372480 bytes (1011 MB)
    JVM Flags: 6 total; -XX:HeapDumpPath=MojangTricksIntelDriversForPerformance_javaw.exe_minecraft.exe.heapdump -Xmx1G -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+CMSIncrementalMode -XX:-UseAdaptiveSizePolicy -Xmn128M
    AABB Pool Size: 0 (0 bytes; 0 MB) allocated, 0 (0 bytes; 0 MB) used
    IntCache: cache: 0, tcache: 0, allocated: 0, tallocated: 0
    Launched Version: 1.7.10
    LWJGL: 2.9.1
    OpenGL: GeForce GTX 750 Ti/PCIe/SSE2 GL version 4.4.0 NVIDIA 344.75, NVIDIA Corporation
    GL Caps: Using GL 1.3 multitexturing.
Using framebuffer objects because OpenGL 3.0 is supported and separate blending is supported.
Anisotropic filtering is supported and maximum anisotropy is 16.
Shaders are available because OpenGL 2.1 is supported.

    Is Modded: Probably not. Jar signature remains and client brand is untouched.
    Type: Client (map_client.txt)
    Resource Packs: []
    Current Language: English (US)
    Profiler Position: N/A (disabled)
    Vec3 Pool Size: 0 (0 bytes; 0 MB) allocated, 0 (0 bytes; 0 MB) used
    Anisotropic Filtering: Off (1)
```

Comment: Have you played 1.8 on the launcher? if so your problem might occur if in the Minecraft folder you have an "options.txt" file with a render distance set really high (Because of 1.8). From what I read, "Minecraft doesn't validate that the render distance is a supported value before trying to use it (apparently)." http://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/support/unmodified-minecraft-client/2330939-minecraft-crashes-every-time-i-open-in-1-7-9-and-1?comment=6 . 

Try deleting the options.txt file maybe and see if that fixes the problem?

Comment: @TonyWhite I hate to give you conflicting advice, I really do. But I am 99% sure this is the solution. The exact crash report is present here and in your source (and in [other sources](http://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/support/modded-client-support/2373782-i-tried-to-add-pixelmon-and-now-my-minecraft)), and the solution is the same. There is no way this is a coincidence, and I don't agree that this is a guess.

Comment: @TonyWhite The "I want to play Minecraft in 1.7.10" sounds a lot like they're downgrading from 1.8 (for some reason), so it's a good educated guess. I've rephrased your guess to an assertion in your answer, so you can see what difference it makes.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie Thanks, I wasn't sure where to go with it. I hate being bold about something especially when it comes to java errors x_x

Answer (score 14):

You have probably played 1.8 in this launcher. Your problem is likely due to `options.txt` in the Minecraft folder file having a render distance set really high (because of 1.8). From what I read, "Minecraft doesn't validate that the render distance is a supported value before trying to use it (apparently)." -[Source](http://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/support/unmodified-minecraft-client/2330939-minecraft-crashes-every-time-i-open-in-1-7-9-and-1?comment=6)

Deleting the `options.txt` file is the fix for this crash for most people who experience it.

Comment: Thx it worked !!